# Convert Daily Dataframe with Multi Index to quarterly

Tags: python, pandas, frequency

I would like to convert my daily dataframe of stock data to a quarterly one. However, using resample did not work, because I have a multi index, so I would like my final quarterly dataframe to still contain the individual stocks (resample just summarizes all of them):

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = [
        {'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-27','returns': 0.2},
        {'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-28','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'ge','date': '2016-11-27','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'ge','date': '2016-11-28','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-27','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-28','returns': 0.2},
]
df1= pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1=df1.set_index(['date','ticker'], drop=True)
```

My final result is supposed to be:

```
Q42016 JPM  0.2
Q42016 GE   0.2
Q42016 AMZ  0.2
```

When I used resample, I get:

```
Q42016  0.2
```

Also, I am stuck with Pandas 0.18 (long story). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is create `DatetimeIndex` by convert `ticker` to column, then use `groupby` with [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

```
df1 = df1.reset_index('ticker').groupby('ticker').resample('Q').mean()
print (df1)
                   returns
ticker date               
amzn   2016-12-31      0.2
ge     2016-12-31      0.2
jpm    2016-12-31      0.2
```

Another solution with [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df1 = df1.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='Q', level='date'), 'ticker']).mean()
print (df1)
                   returns
date       ticker         
2016-12-31 amzn        0.2
           ge          0.2
           jpm         0.2
```

---

For quarter periods use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and then aggregate by `groupby`:

```
df1 = (df1.reset_index()
          .assign(date = lambda x: x['date'].dt.to_period('Q'))
          .groupby(['date','ticker'])
          .mean())
print (df1)
               returns
date   ticker         
2016Q4 amzn        0.2
       ge          0.2
       jpm         0.2
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks also for providing multiple approaches!!