# What is the use of Periods in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, period

I was going through the Periods in pandas and couldnt find any particular use for it and i dont think it is any different from the date, for instance

1. To get the datetime, I use

   datetime(2012,1,1)
2. To get a range of dates, I use

   pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10)

My question is, why would one use Period? According to the definition

> Periods represent timespans, like days, months, quarters, or years.
>
> p = pd.Period(2007, freq='A-DEC')
>
> In this case, the Period object represents the full timespan from
> January 1, 2007, to December 31, 2007, inclusive.
> But if i go by definition, i should be able to groupby using the Period as i holds a range of timespan, but when i try to groupby, i am getting error

```
_period=pd.Period('2000',freq='M')
x = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=14)
_result=pd.Series(range(len(x)),index=x)
_result.groupby(_period)
```

can anyone please help me understand when should i use Period and what and all problems can i solve using it

Answer (score 1):

For aggregate by periods convert `DatetimeIndex` to `PeriodIndex` here by [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
print (_result.index.to_period('m'))
PeriodIndex(['2000-01', '2000-01', '2000-01', '2000-01', '2000-01', '2000-01',
             '2000-01', '2000-01', '2000-01', '2000-01', '2000-01', '2000-01',
             '2000-01', '2000-01'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')

print (_result.groupby(_result.index.to_period('m')).sum())
2000-01    91
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Comment: can you help me on, when to use Period or what is the key difference between Period and Datetime

Comment: @LijinDurairaj - It is used for `[Regular intervals of time are represented by Period objects in pandas while sequences of Period objects are collected in a PeriodIndex,](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#time-span-representation)`. It means practically if need processing e.g. data by months and years is possible use `df.years with df.moths` or `dt.to_periods('m')` for working with months periods. It shuld be altrnative to `pd.Grouper(freq='m')`.

Comment: What is means practically is possible seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908902/convert-daily-dataframe-with-multi-index-to-quarterly/58908933#58908933)

Comment: i have gone through the link which you have provided, now my question is what is the difference between Period and Datetime, when Period can add year, month, day and time like the Datetime, thanks for your help